# The boost asio endpoint class

Tags: networking, boost, boost-asio

As described in the boost documentation :

```
ip::basic_endpoint::port (1 of 2 overloads)
unsigned short port() const;
```

This getter gets the port associated with the endpoint. **The port number is always in the host's byte order.**

I know that Little-endian byte ordering places the least significant byte first. 
However, Big-endian byte ordering places the most significant byte first.

in C language, we use those functions :

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);
uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);
uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

How to get the correct port number in boost asio?

Thanks

Comment: Further thought: the naming of the functions is a good confirmation of my answer: In C you'd call `ntoh` to convert from network byte order to host byte order. As you can se there is no need here, because that has already been done (the value is guaranteed to be in host order, which is the only "correct" one - even if it might look different on the wire).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/port.html

> This getter gets the port associated with the endpoint. The port number is always in the host's byte order.

So, since you call the function on that host, just calling the function returns you the correct port.

I suppose this "strange" comment came about when the authors of the library were implementing the lower layers of some protocols/thinking of raw sockets. Just a warning that you need to do the transformation to network byte order if you are implementing specific protocols. This makes the comment almost completely redundant at the level of abstraction that `basic_endpoint` provides, but who knows maybe it was something someone forgot to adhere to once when implementing (a specialization of) it.

Comment: It's not the case with me. Here is my sample : 
./udp_client 30000 : send a datagram to the server using the port 3000 (c client)
./udp_server outputs :
reply sent to client : port 45227
Here is the code :


`void handle_send(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message,
                          const boost::system::error_code& error,
                          std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
 std::cout << "reply sent to client : port "<< remote_endpoint.port() << std::endl;
}

Comment: I can't see a thing in that messy comment. Why don't you just add that example to the question, where it can be properly formatted and include the code?

Comment: Meanwhile my pocket calculator (bash) says that it's not likely an issue of endianness: https://i.imgur.com/9FsEFin.png

Comment: yes It's not, the issue here is that the protocol used is connectionless.

Comment: @RogerWorld if you reframe the question, perhaps your answer will help others in the future, so go ahead and post

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the UDP is a connectionless protocol. Therefore, the remote_endpoint holds a garbage after sending data.

The code that proves that

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint = socket.remote_endpoint(ec);
if(ec)
{
    std::cout << "An error occurred." << '\n';
    std::cout << ec.value() << " " << ec.message() << '\n';
    return;
}
```

output :

An error occurred.
107 Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: Why are you using remote_endpoint on socket? If you send data by `async_send_to` you need to define endpoint where data is sent, isn't it? So you know remote endpoint. When you read data by `async_receive_from` you know the endpoint of sender also, because you have to pass endpoint object which is filled by sender address.

Comment: @rafix07
Why are you using remote_endpoint on socket : Yes I need it because I have a server so I want to know which client is sending me data. 

If you send data by async_send_to you need to define endpoint where data is sent, isn't it?: I do not define any endpoint, it's transmitted by the async_receive_from method.

Till now I'm unable to recover the port from the remote_endpoint (the sender i.e. the client))

Comment: At server side you create `socket`. You need to bind it to some port - `X` to listen. The client knows where must connect, so it calls `async_send_to` with endpoint which has server IP with `X` port. At server you call `async_receive_from` passing empty endpoint (which is filled by client's address), then you read port from endpoint and you knows where the data comes from.

Comment: yes, but for udp which is connectionless the handler executed after the async_receive_from asynchrounous method does not have the remote_endpoint as parameter.

void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
  std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes received.
);